# Pi appears as offline according to Xfinity router even though it IS connected

Tags: connection, internet, troubleshooting

I'm SSH-ing into a Pi right now, so it is definitely connected to the network. It is connected via Ethernet. The Pi is running default Raspbian. Other Wi-Fi and Ethernet devices that are connected show as online, but the Pi, which has its own IP and is currently working, shows as offline.

Why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done a quick search through some forums related to this router and the issue is not unique to the Pi. Apparently the same behavior is observed with Apple devices as well.

The best thing I can suggest is restarting the router and seeing if it makes any difference. The problem lies somewhere in the software which detects whether a device is connected. Clearly the rest of the functionality of the router works as the Pi has a network connection.

I know the Pi not showing up under connected devices might be annoying if you do have to resolve a network issue with it in the future, but as everything else is working I wouldn't worry about it too much.

For further reading you might be interested in this [thread](http://forums.xfinity.com/t5/Your-Home-Network/Arris-TG862-Not-showing-connected-devices/td-p/1496209), and also this [one](http://forums.xfinity.com/t5/Your-Home-Network/Re-Arris-TG862-Not-showing-connected-devices/m-p/2022951#U2022951). From what I've read there this is a big problem with the router. If you want a fix calling out your ISP is one option. Although, to be honest with you ISP provided equipment is normally notoriously low quality so you could use this as an excuse to invest in some nicer networking equipment.

Comment: You could set a static IP to make resolving future network issues easier.

Comment: True, but even if you know the IP address of the Pi it might be your unable to ping it for some reason related to the Pi. In that case being able to look in the router settings to see if it shows up as connected is useful. And it is something I have needed to do in the past.

Comment: Having a static IP doesn't stop you from looking at the router info.

Comment: That's not what I was suggesting. My point was even if you have a static IP if something quirky happens on the software side of things with the Pi and you can't SSH into it e.t.c... A quick check to see if it has a network connection is to go into the router settings and look under connected devices. This is much quicker than having to hook up a monitor to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Thank you, and sorry for being so late to mark as answered.